# Powershell loop to call Disk Cleanup

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to loop through a list of Windows machines in the domain to call for Disk Cleanup however, because the way the list is returned it's not executing the ForEach statement with the name substituted. Can anyone provide some guidance on how to make this work?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "*windows*"} -Property * | Format-Table Name |  foreach {Echo "psexec \\$ cleanmgr /sagerun:1"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working exactly the way I had wanted and with specific OU.

```
ForEach ($COMPUTER in (Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -Like "*OU=Employee's Computers,DC=company,DC=com"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)) { .\psexec \\$COMPUTER cleanmgr /sagerun:1 }
```

Comment: You can speed up the query by using: 
`Get-ADComputer -searchRoot "OU=Employee's Computers,DC=company,DC=com"`
PowerShell will then not load all computers from the AD, only the ones you need.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It's complaining about the `-searchRoot`.

Answer (score 0):

something  like this

```
$computers = get-Content c:\computers.txt
foreach ($computer in $computers){
if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
{write-host "cannot reach $computer" -f red}

else {& \\$computer\C$\Windows\System32\cleanmgr.exe /sagerun:1}}
```

Comment: didn't tried with can you check

`$computers=Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -Like "*windows*"} -Property * | Format-Table Name`

Comment: Will this not just run the remote `cleanmgr.exe` on your local computer?

Comment: it wll run on remote computers too and no need pstools + you can get info on which computer it was nit run